# Scala for-loop ranges OutOfMemoryError

Tags: scala, for-loop, range, out-of-memory, lazy-evaluation

Why does `for {i <- (1 to 1000000000)} println(i)` gives me OutOfMemoryError but `(1 to 1000000000) foreach println` does not? What if I have to use the for-loop syntax, what should I do?

Comment: the for loop allocates 10^9 ints

Comment: What version of scala is this related to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two fragments are nearly equivalent. `for` syntax in scala is desugared by the compiler into applications of `foreach`, `flatmap`, `withFilter` as well as `map` (if you use `yield`). This information can be found in section 6.19 of the [scala language specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf).

That means the `for` loop

```
for (i <- 1 to 1000000000) println(i)
```

becomes desugared into

```
(1 to 1000000000).foreach { case i => println(i) }
```

which is nearly equivalent to

```
(1 to 1000000000) foreach println
```

Neither of the fragments should cause an OutOfMemoryError. You can have a look at the overridden definition of `foreach` for `Range`s in the sources:

https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.10.1/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Range.scala#L135

There is only 1 index variable which is mutated while the loop is processed.

But it's useful to confirm that there is no extra boxing/unboxing of the index int.  As it turns out, there isn't, although the stack trace to get there is slightly different for the two forms:

```
Predef$.println(Object) line: 287
ForTest$$anonfun$f$1.apply$mcVI$sp(Int) line: 5
Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Function1) line: 141
ForTest$.f() line: 5

Predef$.println(Object) line: 287
ForTest$$anonfun$g$1.apply(Object) line: 6
ForTest$$anonfun$g$1.apply(Object) line: 6  // boxing here
Function1$class.apply$mcVI$sp(Function1, Int) line: 39
AbstractFunction1.apply$mcVI$sp(Int) line: 12
Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Function1) line: 141
ForTest$.g() line: 6
```